# Problema con proyecto en Python

Tags: python

En la universidad me dejaron como proyecto lo siguiente:
[image: Imagen proyecto]
Me gustaría saber cómo poder ingresar en lo que llevo de mi código la parte de la imagen que dice *Existe una condición persistente en el software (...). Se debe repartir equitativamente y al sumar el valor que lo hace impar al porcentaje más bajo"*. Esa parte no entiendo cómo incluirla en mi código, lo demás tengo una idea de cómo hacerlo, pero me da miedo seguir avanzando en mi código ya que pienso que a la hora de ingresar esa condición me tocaría cambiar el código, o parte de este, así que quiero desarrollar esa condición antes de seguir elaborando el código, pero como dije antes, no sé cómo hacerla.

Acá dejo una explicación de parte de mi profesor con respecto a la condición:

NotaEjercicio = 5, NotaProyecto = 5, NotaParcial = 5 PorcentajeEjercicio = 10, PorcentajeProyecto = 10, PorcentajeParcial = 15

si es este, no se mueven los valores, Si NotaProyecto ó NotaParcial son menores (<) al 60% de la NotaEjercicio (NotaEjercicio*0.6), entonces se cancela el porcentaje de ejercicio y se reparte, ósea, NotaEjercicio = 5, NotaProyecto = 2, NotaParcial = 1, eso es en el caso que el PorcentajeEjercicio sea PAR

Si es impar hay que darle Mas al de menor porcentaje. Por ejemplo: NotaEjercicio = 5, NotaProyecto = 5, NotaParcial = 5 PorcentajeEjercicio = 5, PorcentajeProyecto = 10, PorcentajeParcial = 15

Entonces, si le fuera mal se haría lo siguiente: NotaEjercicio = 5, NotaProyecto = 2, NotaParcial = 1 PorcentajeEjercicio = 0, PorcentajeProyecto = 13, PorcentajeParcial = 17

Acá dejo lo que tengo como "código":

```
#"Aplicación" para calcular notas finales del curso

#pedir notas Corte 1,2 y 3

C1_Taller=float(input("ingrese las notas del taller corte1:"))
C1_Proyecto=float(input("ingrese las notas del proyecto corte1:"))
C1_Parcial=float(input("ingrese las notas del parcial corte1:"))

#Porcentajes Corte 1
print("Tenga en cuenta que en el corte 1 el taller vale 10%,El proyecto 10% y el parcial 15%")

C2_Taller=float(input("ingrese las notas del taller corte2:"))
C2_Proyecto=float(input("ingrese las notas del proyecto corte2:"))
C2_Parcial=float(input("ingrese las notas del parcial corte2:"))

#Porcentajes Corte 2
print("Tenga en cuenta que en el corte 2 el taller vale 10%,El proyecto 10% y el parcial 15%")

C3_Taller=float(input("ingrese las notas del taller corte3:"))
C3_Proyecto=float(input("ingrese las notas del proyecto corte3:"))
C3_Parcial=float(input("ingrese las notas del parcial corte3:"))

#Porcentajes Corte 3
print("Tenga en cuenta que en el corte 3 el taller vale 5%,El proyecto 10% y el parcial 15%")

#promedios
PromedioTalleres=(C1_Taller+C2_Taller+C3_Taller)/(3)
print("El promedio de los talleres de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioTalleres,2))

PromedioProyectos=(C1_Proyecto+C2_Proyecto+C3_Proyecto)/(3)
print("El promedio de los proyectos de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioProyectos,2))

PromedioParciales=(C1_Parcial+C2_Parcial+C3_Parcial)/(3)
print("El promedio de los parciales de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioParciales,2))

#porcentajes
C1_PorcentajeTaller=(C1_Taller*10)/(100)
C1_PorcentajeProyecto=(C1_Proyecto*10)/(100)
C1_PorcentajeParcial=(C1_Parcial*15)/(100)

C2_PorcentajeTaller=(C2_Taller*10)/(100)
C2_PorcentajeProyecto=(C2_Proyecto*10)/(100)
C2_PorcentajeParcial=(C2_Parcial*15)/(100)

C3_PorcentajeTaller=(C3_Taller*5)/(100)
C3_PorcentajeProyecto=(C3_Proyecto*10)/(100)
C3_PorcentajeParcial=(C3_Parcial*15)/(100)

#promedio porcentajes
PromedioPorcentajesTalleres=(C1_PorcentajeTaller+C2_PorcentajeTaller+C3_PorcentajeTaller)
print("El promedio del porcentaje de los talleres de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioPorcentajesTalleres,2))
PromedioPorcentajesProyectos=(C1_PorcentajeProyecto+C2_PorcentajeProyecto+C3_PorcentajeProyecto)
print("El promedio del porcentaje de los proyectos de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioPorcentajesProyectos,2))
PromedioPorcentajesParciales=(C1_PorcentajeParcial+C2_PorcentajeParcial+C3_PorcentajeParcial)
print("El promedio del porcentaje de los parciales de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioPorcentajesParciales,2))
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Buen día, lei el enunciado pero honestamente yo creo que está mal escrito y no se entiende, yo en tu lugar le pediría al profesor un ejemplo de lo que quiso decir. O podría ser que tu ya has solicitado la aclaración, en ese caso por favor pon un ejemplo con valores numéricos de lo que quiere decir ese enunciado y como sería el resultado.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato, no le he solicitado esa aclaración al profesor, mañana cuando vaya a la U le pediré al profesor que me aclare esa parte para poder publicarla y que quede mas entendible la pregunta, gracias por la información.

Comment: Lo mejor sería que te diera un ejemplo con números y que te explique el procedimiento.

Comment: Por favor, pon el enunciado _como texto_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Además, pon en el título cuál es el problema en cuestión: recuerda que la pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para otros lectores que lleguen a tener un problema similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He editado la respuesta esta seria todo el codigo que tenias hecho mas la parte que tenias dudas:

```
    #"Aplicación" para calcular notas finales del curso

#pedir notas Corte 1,2 y 3
#Porcentajes Corte 1
print("Tenga en cuenta que en el corte 1 el taller vale 10%,El proyecto 10% y el parcial 15%")
C1_Taller=float(input("ingrese las notas del taller corte1:"))
C1_Proyecto=float(input("ingrese las notas del proyecto corte1:"))
C1_Parcial=float(input("ingrese las notas del parcial corte1:"))


#Porcentajes Corte 2
print("Tenga en cuenta que en el corte 2 el taller vale 10%,El proyecto 10% y el parcial 15%")
C2_Taller=float(input("ingrese las notas del taller corte2:"))
C2_Proyecto=float(input("ingrese las notas del proyecto corte2:"))
C2_Parcial=float(input("ingrese las notas del parcial corte2:"))


#Porcentajes Corte 3
print("Tenga en cuenta que en el corte 3 el taller vale 5%,El proyecto 10% y el parcial 15%")
C3_Taller=float(input("ingrese las notas del taller corte3:"))
C3_Proyecto=float(input("ingrese las notas del proyecto corte3:"))
C3_Parcial=float(input("ingrese las notas del parcial corte3:"))



#promedios
PromedioTalleres=(C1_Taller+C2_Taller+C3_Taller)/3
print("El promedio de los talleres de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioTalleres,2))

PromedioProyectos=(C1_Proyecto+C2_Proyecto+C3_Proyecto)/3
print("El promedio de los proyectos de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioProyectos,2))

PromedioParciales=(C1_Parcial+C2_Parcial+C3_Parcial)/3
print("El promedio de los parciales de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioParciales,2))

#porcentajes
C1_PorcentajeTaller=(C1_Taller*10)/100
C1_PorcentajeProyecto=(C1_Proyecto*10)/100
C1_PorcentajeParcial=(C1_Parcial*15)/100

C2_PorcentajeTaller=(C2_Taller*10)/100
C2_PorcentajeProyecto=(C2_Proyecto*10)/100
C2_PorcentajeParcial=(C2_Parcial*15)/100

C3_PorcentajeTaller=(C3_Taller*5)/(100)
C3_PorcentajeProyecto=(C3_Proyecto*10)/(100)
C3_PorcentajeParcial=(C3_Parcial*15)/(100)

#primera corte comparacion de porcentajes 
if C1_PorcentajeParcial<60 or  C1_PorcentajeProyecto<60: # primera comparacion de porcentajes
    Dividido= C1_PorcentajeProyecto/2
    C1_PorcentajeProyecto+=Dividido
    C1_PorcentajeParcial+=Dividido
    Residuo= C1_PorcentajeParcial%2
    if Residuo!=0:  #es impar si residuo no  es igual a 0
        if C1_PorcentajeParcial<C1_PorcentajeProyecto: # al ser impar miramos cual es mas pequeño 
        C1_PorcentajeParcial+=Residuo 
        elif C1_PorcentajeParcial>C1_PorcentajeProyecto:
            C1_PorcentajeProyecto+=Residuo
        else:# si son iguales repartimos el residuo por igual (no se especifica es mi hipotesis consultar al profesor)
            C1_PorcentajeProyecto=C1_PorcentajeProyecto+(Residuo/2) #los parentesis no hacen falta debido a la prioridad de operaciones
            C1_PorcentajeParcial=C1_PorcentajeParcial+(Residuo/2) 
#Segundo corte comparacion de porcentajes 
if C2_PorcentajeParcial<60 or  C2_PorcentajeProyecto<60: # primera comparacion de porcentajes
    Dividido= C2_PorcentajeProyecto/2
    C2_PorcentajeProyecto+=Dividido
    C2_PorcentajeParcial+=Dividido
    Residuo= C2_PorcentajeParcial%2
    if Residuo!=0:  #es impar si residuo no  es igual a 0
        if C2_PorcentajeParcial<C2_PorcentajeProyecto: # al ser impar miramos cual es mas pequeño 
        C2_PorcentajeParcial+=Residuo 
        elif C2_PorcentajeParcial>C2_PorcentajeProyecto:
            C2_PorcentajeProyecto+=Residuo
        else:# si son iguales repartimos el residuo por igual (no se especifica es mi hipotesis consultar al profesor)
            C2_PorcentajeProyecto=C2_PorcentajeProyecto+(Residuo/2) #los parentesis no hacen falta debido a la prioridad de operaciones
            C2_PorcentajeParcial=C2_PorcentajeParcial+(Residuo/2) 
#Tercer corte comparacion de porcentajes 
if C3_PorcentajeParcial<60 or  C3_PorcentajeProyecto<60: # primera comparacion de porcentajes
    Dividido= C3_PorcentajeProyecto/2
    C3_PorcentajeProyecto+=Dividido
    C3_PorcentajeParcial+=Dividido
    Residuo= C3_PorcentajeParcial%2
    if Residuo!=0:  #es impar si residuo no  es igual a 0
        if C3_PorcentajeParcial<C3_PorcentajeProyecto: # al ser impar miramos cual es mas pequeño 
        C3_PorcentajeParcial+=Residuo 
        elif C3_PorcentajeParcial>C3_PorcentajeProyecto:
            C3_PorcentajeProyecto+=Residuo
        else:# si son iguales repartimos el residuo por igual (no se especifica es mi hipotesis consultar al profesor)
            C3_PorcentajeProyecto=C3_PorcentajeProyecto+(Residuo/2) #los parentesis no hacen falta debido a la prioridad de operaciones
            C3_PorcentajeParcial=C3_PorcentajeParcial+(Residuo/2) 
#promedio porcentajes
PromedioPorcentajesTalleres=(C1_PorcentajeTaller+C2_PorcentajeTaller+C3_PorcentajeTaller)
print("El promedio del porcentaje de los talleres de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioPorcentajesTalleres,2))
PromedioPorcentajesProyectos=(C1_PorcentajeProyecto+C2_PorcentajeProyecto+C3_PorcentajeProyecto)
print("El promedio del porcentaje de los proyectos de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioPorcentajesProyectos,2))
PromedioPorcentajesParciales=(C1_PorcentajeParcial+C2_PorcentajeParcial+C3_PorcentajeParcial)
print("El promedio del porcentaje de los parciales de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioPorcentajesParciales,2))
```

Se tiene que usar los condicionales para saber si son menores uno o el otro.
**%** sirve para obtener el residuo de la división.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato,@rexxarcat, con respecto a la condición el profesor me respondió lo siguiente: 

NotaEjercicio = 5, NotaProyecto = 5, NotaParcial = 5
PorcentajeEjercicio = 10, PorcentajeProyecto = 10, PorcentajeParcial = 15,

si es este, no se mueven los valores,

Si NotaProyecto ó NotaParcial son menores (<) al 60% de la NotaEjercicio (NotaEjercicio*0.6),

entonces se cancela el porcentaje de ejercicio y se reparte,osea,

NotaEjercicio = 5, NotaProyecto = 2, NotaParcial = 1,

eso es en el caso que el PorcentajeEjercicio sea PAR 

**SIGO RESPONDIENDO EN OTRO COMENTARIO**

Comment: Si es impar hay que darle Mas al de menor porcentaje.

Por ejemplo:

NotaEjercicio = 5, NotaProyecto = 5, NotaParcial = 5
PorcentajeEjercicio = 5, PorcentajeProyecto = 10, PorcentajeParcial = 15,

Entonces, si le fuera mal se haria lo siguiente:

NotaEjercicio = 5, NotaProyecto = 2, NotaParcial = 1
PorcentajeEjercicio = 0, PorcentajeProyecto = 13, PorcentajeParcial = 17,

Eso fue todo lo que me dijo, **la verdad sigo sin saber como incluir esa condición en lo que llevo de código**, y me gustaría saber si me podrían ayudar en eso, gracias

Comment: @JoséHidalgo lo único que falta y que no aclara el professor es que hacer con el residuo por ejemplo PorcentajeEjercicio=15, PorcentajeProyecto=10, PorcentajeParcial=10 yo he hecho mi suposición pero tendrías que aclararlo.

Comment: @JoséHidalgo las aclaraciones debes colocarlas como edición a la pregunta. Los comentarios son efímeros.

Comment: @rexxarcat Gracias a lo tuyo comprendí más el ejercicio, la condición básicamente se trata de lo siguiente: Si la nota que tiene el parcial o el proyecto es menor al 60% de la nota del taller, entonces lo que hay que hacer es repartir el porcentaje del taller, en el caso del corte 1 el taller vale 10, así que esto se hay que repartir equitativamente en el porcentaje del proyecto y el parcial, ósea, el proyecto valía antes 10% y parcial 15%, ahora valdrían 15% y 20%,pero esto solo será si el porcentaje es par, así que solo seria para el Corte 1 y 2, **EN OTRO COMENTARIO SIGO EXPLICANDO**

Comment: Ahora, para el caso que el porcentaje sea impar, esto seria para el corte 3, si  la nota del taller es 5, el proyecto es 2 y el parcial es 1, el porcentaje del taller se repartirá equitativamente y se sumaria al valor que lo hace impar, antes valdría el taller 5%, el proyecto 10% y el parcial 15%, según el ejemplo numérico que te di arriba, los porcentajes cambiarían a los siguientes: el del taller ahora seria 0%, el del proyecto seria 13% y el del parcial seria 17%, básicamente eso es lo que tiene que hacer la condición.