# Encontrar la nota mas baja e imprimirla junto a su ubicación PYTHON

Tags: python

Buenos días/tardes/noches, Necesito ayuda con lo siguiente: En mi universidad me dejaron un proyecto, en este basicamente lo que hay que hacer es ingresar unas notas, cada nota tiene su porcentaje, ejemplo: proyecto: 10%, Taller:10%,Parcial:15%, estas notas se dividen en 3 cortes, cada corte tiene sus porcentajes, el caso es que necesito que mi algoritmo imprima cual es la nota mas baja y donde está ubicada, ejemplo: Proyecto:5,Taller:3, Parcial:1, quiero que mi algoritmo diga que la nota mas baja es el parcial, y que la nota de esta es 1, además de esto quiero que me diga donde se ubica esa nota, ejemplo: "la nota mas baja es parcial Corte 1: con una nota de 1", basicamente eso es en lo que necesito ayuda, pero no entiendo como hacerlo.

Acá dejo lo que llevo de mi codigo:

```
#"Aplicación" para calcular notas finales del curso

#Porcentajes Corte 1
print("Tenga en cuenta que en el corte 1 el taller vale 10%,El proyecto 10% y el parcial 15%")

#pedir notas Corte 1,2 y 3
C1_Taller=float(input("ingrese las notas del taller corte1:"))
C1_Proyecto=float(input("ingrese las notas del proyecto corte1:"))
C1_Parcial=float(input("ingrese las notas del parcial corte1:"))

#Porcentajes Corte 2
print("Tenga en cuenta que en el corte 2 el taller vale 10%,El proyecto 10% y el parcial 15%")

C2_Taller=float(input("ingrese las notas del taller corte2:"))
C2_Proyecto=float(input("ingrese las notas del proyecto corte2:"))
C2_Parcial=float(input("ingrese las notas del parcial corte2:"))

#Porcentajes Corte 3
print("Tenga en cuenta que en el corte 3 el taller vale 5%,El proyecto 10% y el parcial 15%")

C3_Taller=float(input("ingrese las notas del taller corte3:"))
C3_Proyecto=float(input("ingrese las notas del proyecto corte3:"))
C3_Parcial=float(input("ingrese las notas del parcial corte3:"))

#promedios
PromedioTalleres=(C1_Taller+C2_Taller+C3_Taller)/(3)
print("El promedio de los talleres de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioTalleres,2))

PromedioProyectos=(C1_Proyecto+C2_Proyecto+C3_Proyecto)/(3)
print("El promedio de los proyectos de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioProyectos,2))

PromedioParciales=(C1_Parcial+C2_Parcial+C3_Parcial)/(3)
print("El promedio de los parciales de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioParciales,2))

#porcentajes
C1_PorcentajeTaller=(C1_Taller*10)/(100)
print("El porcentaje del taller C1 es",C1_PorcentajeTaller)
C1_PorcentajeProyecto=(C1_Proyecto*10)/(100)
print("El porcentaje del proyecto C1 es",C1_PorcentajeProyecto)
C1_PorcentajeParcial=(C1_Parcial*15)/(100)
print("El porcentaje del parcial C1 es",C1_PorcentajeParcial)

C2_PorcentajeTaller=(C2_Taller*10)/(100)
print("El porcentaje del taller C2 es",C2_PorcentajeTaller)
C2_PorcentajeProyecto=(C2_Proyecto*10)/(100)
print("El porcentaje del proyecto C2 es",C2_PorcentajeProyecto)
C2_PorcentajeParcial=(C2_Parcial*15)/(100)
print("El porcentaje del parcial C2 es",C2_PorcentajeParcial)

C3_PorcentajeTaller=(C3_Taller*5)/(100)
print("El porcentaje del taller C3 es",C3_PorcentajeTaller)
C3_PorcentajeProyecto=(C3_Proyecto*10)/(100)
print("El porcentaje del proyecto C3 es",C3_PorcentajeProyecto)
C3_PorcentajeParcial=(C3_Parcial*15)/(100)
print("El porcentaje del parcial C3 es",C3_PorcentajeParcial)

#CONDICIÓN

if C1_Proyecto<C1_Taller*0.6 or C1_Parcial<C1_Taller*0.6:
    C1_PorcentajeTallerPar=C1_PorcentajeTaller/2
    C1_PorcentajeTallerNuevo=0
    print("El nuevo porcentaje del taller C1 es",C1_PorcentajeTallerNuevo)
    C1_PorcentajeProyectoPar=(C1_Proyecto*15)/(100)
    print("El nuevo porcentaje del proyecto C1 es",C1_PorcentajeProyectoPar)
    C1_PorcentajeParcialPar=(C1_Parcial*20)/(100)
    print("El nuevo porcentaje del parcial C1 es",C1_PorcentajeParcialPar)

if C2_Proyecto<C2_Taller*0.6 or C2_Parcial<C2_Taller*0.6:
    C2_PorcentajeTallerPar=C2_PorcentajeTaller/2
    C2_PorcentajeTallerNuevo=0
    print("El nuevo porcentaje del taller C2 es",C2_PorcentajeTallerNuevo)
    C2_PorcentajeProyectoPar=(C2_Proyecto*15)/(100)
    print("El nuevo porcentaje del proyecto C2 es",C2_PorcentajeProyectoPar)
    C2_PorcentajeParcialPar=(C2_Parcial*20)/(100)
    print("El nuevo porcentaje del parcial C2 es",C2_PorcentajeParcialPar)

if C3_Proyecto<C3_Taller*0.6 or C3_Parcial<C3_Taller*0.6:
    #C3_PorcentajeTallerImpar=C3_PorcentajeTaller/2
    C3_PorcentajeTallerNuevo=0
    print("El nuevo porcentaje del taller C3 es",C3_PorcentajeTallerNuevo)

#promedio porcentajes
if C1_Proyecto<C1_Taller*0.6 or C1_Parcial<C1_Taller*0.6 and C2_Proyecto<C2_Taller*0.6 or C2_Parcial<C2_Taller*0.6:
    C1_PorcentajeTaller==0 and C2_PorcentajeTaller==0
    PromedioPorcentajesTalleres=(C1_PorcentajeTaller+C2_PorcentajeTaller+C3_PorcentajeTaller)
    print("El promedio del porcentaje de los talleres de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioPorcentajesTalleres,2))
#PromedioPorcentajesProyectos=(C1_PorcentajeProyecto+C2_PorcentajeProyecto+C3_PorcentajeProyecto)
#print("El promedio del porcentaje de los proyectos de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioPorcentajesProyectos,2))
#PromedioPorcentajesParciales=(C1_PorcentajeParcial+C2_PorcentajeParcial+C3_PorcentajeParcial)
#print("El promedio del porcentaje de los parciales de los 3 cortes es",round(PromedioPorcentajesParciales,2))

NotaC1=C1_PorcentajeTaller+C1_PorcentajeProyecto+C1_PorcentajeParcial
print("La nota del C1 es",round(NotaC1,2),"Esto equivale al 35% de la nota final")
NotaC2=C2_PorcentajeTaller+C2_PorcentajeProyecto+C2_PorcentajeParcial
print("La nota del C2 es",round(NotaC2,2),"Esto equivale al 35% de la nota final")
NotaC3=C3_PorcentajeTaller+C3_PorcentajeProyecto+C3_PorcentajeParcial
print("La nota del C3 es",round(NotaC3,2),"Esto equivale al 30% de la nota final")

NotaDefinitiva=NotaC1+NotaC2+NotaC3
print("La nota definitiva de los 3 cortes es",NotaDefinitiva)
if NotaDefinitiva<3:
    print("REPROBADO")
else:
    print("APROBADO")

NotaMasBaja=
```

**IGNORAR LA PARTE DEL PROMEDIO PORCENTAJES YA QUE ESTA ESTÁ INCOMPLETA**

EDITADO: Respecto a la ayuda que necesito, tengo un avance de este, lo malo es que solo conseguí hacer que me imprimiera la nota mas baja de cada corte, no se como poder que no me imprima todas, si no que me imprima la nota mas baja en general.

Dejo el avance que tengo:

```
if C1_Taller<C1_Proyecto and C1_Taller<C1_Parcial:
    print("La nota mas baja es el taller ubicado en el corte 1,","la nota de este es:",C1_Taller)
else:
    if C1_Proyecto<C1_Taller and C1_Proyecto<C1_Parcial:
        print("La nota mas baja es el proyecto ubicado en el corte 1,","la nota de este es:",C1_Proyecto)
    else:
        C1_Parcial<C1_Taller and C1_Parcial<C1_Proyecto
        print("La nota mas baja es el parcial ubicado en el corte 1,","la nota de este es:",C1_Parcial)

if C2_Taller<C2_Proyecto and C2_Taller<C2_Parcial:
    print("La nota mas baja es el taller ubicado en el corte 2,","la nota de este es:",C2_Taller)
else:
    if C2_Proyecto<C2_Taller and C2_Proyecto<C2_Parcial:
        print("La nota mas baja es el proyecto ubicado en el corte 2,","la nota de este es:",C2_Proyecto)
    else:
        C2_Parcial<C2_Taller and C2_Parcial<C2_Proyecto
        print("La nota mas baja es el parcial ubicado en el corte 2,","la nota de este es:",C2_Parcial)

if C3_Taller<C3_Proyecto and C3_Taller<C3_Parcial:
    print("La nota mas baja es el taller ubicado en el corte 3,","la nota de este es:",C3_Taller)
else:
    if C3_Proyecto<C3_Taller and C3_Proyecto<C3_Parcial:
        print("La nota mas baja es el proyecto ubicado en el corte 3,","la nota de este es:",C3_Proyecto)
    else:
        C3_Parcial<C3_Taller and C3_Parcial<C3_Proyecto
        print("La nota mas baja es el parcial ubicado en el corte 3,","la nota de este es:",C3_Parcial)
```

Comment: ¿En que se diferencia esta de tu anterior pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/554958/problema-con-proyecto-en-python

Comment: @CandidMoe La diferencia es que en la anterior necesitaba ayuda con la condición, aunque en esa publicación no me pudieron ayudar del todo, lo bueno fue que gracias a ella pude descubrir como hacerla, y en esta necesito ayuda con lo que dije en el titulo, el como puedo imprimir la nota mas baja y poner su ubicación, tengo una breve idea de como hacerlo pero no logro que me funcione.